# Second notification with same intent does not start activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent, back-stack

I'm having a problem with notification api. I've looked everywhere, but I found no solution. I'm hoping you guys might help me.

So, here is our problem:

- Application is closed
- Notification received from server (using Firebase)
- Notification clicked and correct activity is started
- Same notification received again
- Notification clicked but nothing happens

The only solution we found to solve this problem was to use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag, but this posed another problem, which is that we want to keep the same back stack history.

Comment: First, verify through logcat that the system issuing a start to your activity and that there isn't some other problem w/ your notification. You should see something like `01-08 09:44:52.810 I/ActivityManager(  713): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN...`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the application is closed and a notification is received and before being clicked, logcat shows this message: 
`01-08 20:31:27.120 752-777/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 5423:tn.duoes.esprit.cookmania/u0a441 for broadcast-3 tn.duoes.esprit.cookmania/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver`

Comment: That's not an activity start. It's saying it is starting the process to handle a broadcast intent.

Comment: It's the only message i'm getting from ActivityManager. where to go from here ?

Comment: It indicates there's a problem with your notification's pending intent. If it's not even trying to start the activity it's not a problem with flags. Ensure you are setting the right pending intent into the notifications in both bases.

Comment: Post the code that you use to build the notification and post your manifest. Add these things to the original post please, do not try to post code in a comment.